# How does one deal with a group of login fields in Yodlee?

Tags: yodlee

For normal username/password fields, it's pretty straight forward with a single key value pair, but I recently encountered a complicated Content Service, which has a group of fields (birth date), do we resubmit in plural form or as if they were separate fields?

Example:
Normal Form:

```
["componentList"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#3 (13) {
        ["valueIdentifier"]=>
        string(5) "LOGIN"
        ["valueMask"]=>
        string(11) "LOGIN_FIELD"
        ["fieldType"]=>
        object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
          ["typeName"]=>
          string(4) "TEXT"
        }
        ["size"]=>
        int(20)
        ["maxlength"]=>
        int(15)
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "LOGIN"
        ["displayName"]=>
        string(7) "User ID"
        ["isEditable"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["isOptional"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["isEscaped"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["helpText"]=>
        string(5) "85046"
        ["isOptionalMFA"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["isMFA"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
```

Weird plural form:

```
[3]=>
      object(stdClass)#11 (19) {
        ["defaultValues"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          NULL
          [1]=>
          NULL
          [2]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["values"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          NULL
          [1]=>
          NULL
          [2]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["validValues"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          array(12) {
            [0]=>
            string(2) "01"
            [1]=>
            string(2) "02"
            [2]=>
            string(2) "03"
            [3]=>
            string(2) "04"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(31) {
            [0]=>
            string(2) "01"
            [1]=>
            string(2) "02"
            [2]=>
            string(2) "03"
            [3]=>
            string(2) "04"
          }
          [2]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["valueIdentifiers"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "OPTIONS1"
          [1]=>
          string(7) "OPTIONS"
          [2]=>
          string(6) "LOGIN1"
        }
        ["valueMasks"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(12) "/LOGIN_FIELD"
          [1]=>
          string(11) "LOGIN_FIELD"
          [2]=>
          string(12) "/LOGIN_FIELD"
        }
        ["fieldTypes"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          object(stdClass)#9 (1) {
            ["typeName"]=>
            string(7) "OPTIONS"
          }
          [1]=>
          object(stdClass)#8 (1) {
            ["typeName"]=>
            string(7) "OPTIONS"
          }
          [2]=>
          object(stdClass)#14 (1) {
            ["typeName"]=>
            string(4) "TEXT"
          }
        }
        ["validationRules"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          NULL
          [1]=>
          NULL
          [2]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["sizes"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          int(20)
          [1]=>
          int(20)
          [2]=>
          int(20)
        }
        ["maxlengths"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          int(40)
          [1]=>
          int(40)
          [2]=>
          int(4)
        }
        ["userProfileMappingExpressions"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          NULL
          [1]=>
          NULL
          [2]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["name"]=>
        string(26) "Date of Birth (MM/DD/YYYY)"
        ["displayName"]=>
        string(26) "Date of Birth (MM/DD/YYYY)"
        ["isEditable"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["isOptional"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["isEscaped"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["helpText"]=>
        string(5) "85043"
        ["isOptionalMFA"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["isMFA"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
```

When sending this grouping back to the API, I currently flattened it so it's like:
credentialFields[3]
credentialFields[4]
credentialFields[5]

With each containing the relevant data for the date, month and year.  However, perhaps we are supposed to roll it up as plurals in the same way it comes down?  Is there an example of one of these multi-value forms for the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct certain financial institutions do have multiple fields in groups, DOB is one of them. I have done successful implementation for the same. Since I did the same in  purely SOAP, however I do not have any sample for REST implementation so what all I can tell you that is you do not need to flatten the list simply fill in the required answers in the original list and send back the form with your request.